# Cant find and click button By.XPath("//button[@title='MyCompany']").Click()

Tags: c#, selenium

Trying to find an click the element of a button "MyCompany". However I get NoSuchElementExist when calling  `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@title='MyCompany']").Click()` ? What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Please don't use [images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: In your image I don't see a `<button>` element with a title attribute having value "MyCompany"

Comment: That is a text, and not text from a title. Try with class, or something else

Comment: Where is the title tag? I only see an empty title tag in the button so that could be the problem.

Comment: DeadSec I see now. I thought the name was contained in the title but it isn't. This explains my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things you can try:

First, use the full xpath (in chrome dev tools, right click element, copy > full Xpath).

Second, because it is angular, sometimes the element likes being in the viewport or the page needs to be loaded all the way first. This can be accomplished by using 'IJavaScriptExecutor'.

```
//use full xpath here instead
var xPathButton = @"//button[@title='MyCompany']";
    using (var driver = new ChromeDriver())
        {

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://website.com);
            //scrolls to bottom to ensure page load
            
           ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight - 1)"); 
            Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
            
            var companyButton = driver.FindElementByXPath(xPathButton);
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", companyButton);
         }
```